# PHP - array_search() fails on === true, but not on !== false?

Tags: php, arrays

When I want to check if something is in the array and get the key back, I use the [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function.

Why is it when I compare the function to be exactly equal to true (=== true) it returns false, and when I compare it to not be exactly equal to false (!== false) it returns true?

```
<?php
    if(array_search($value, $array) === true)
    {
        // Fails
    }

    if(array_search($value, $array) !== false)
    {
        // Succeeds
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns you needle when a match is found. it returns false only when match is not found. This is why only the opposite works in your case.

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE
>   otherwise.

Comment: Ahh, it makes sense now. Thanks Hasan.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but wanted to add some context / examples:

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will return the **key** (if the value is found) - which could be `0` - and will return `FALSE` if the value is *not found*.  It **never** returns `TRUE`.

This code may sum it up better:

```
// test array...
$array = [
    0   => 'First Item',
    1   => 'Second Item',
    'x' => 'Associative Item'
];

// example results:
$key = array_search( 'First Item', $array );       // returns 0
$key = array_search( 'Second Item', $array );      // returns 1
$key = array_search( 'Associative Item', $array ); // returns 'x'
$key = array_search( 'Third Item', $array );       // returns FALSE
```

Since `0` is a falsey value, you wouldn't want to do something like `if ( ! array_search(...) ) {`... because it would fail on `0` index items.

Therefore, the way to use it is something like:

```
$key = array_search( 'Third Item', $array ); // returns FALSE
if ( FALSE !== $key ) {
    // item was found, key is in $index, do something here...
}
```

It's worth mentioning this is also true of functions like [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), so it's a good pattern to get in the habit of following.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) does not return true.

If will only return **false**, if it can't find anything, otherwise it will return the key of the matched element.

*According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)*

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful
> ....
>
> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: As per @Hasan Khan, it does return FALSE

Comment: @allen213, It was not incorrect, you would understand better if I had written `boolean`

Comment: originally you wrote array_search does not return true of false

Comment: @allen213, I didn't disagree to that did I? I should have written array_search() does not return `boolean`. But, no body bothered to read the line after. Ha ha

Answer (score 0):

It will fail because if the call is succesfull it returns the key no true.

false is returned if it isnt found so === false is ok

from the manual:

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.